# How to edit my macro to ignore text in a certain color(blue) when exporting sheets into a pdf report?

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on some simple VBA code executed by clicking a button. This button exports the sheets into a pdf format.

code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name, Sheet3.Name, Sheet4.Name)).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Some location", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, 
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Intro").Select
```

I was wondering if it's possible to add an IF statement that would go through all sheets and skip publishing whatever is written in blue color (any variant if possible e.g. any shade of blue). The reason I want to designate this color to ensure comments can be written in blue and not be printed in the official pdf report produced by this macro.

Thank you!

Comment: Change all the Blue to White, create the PDF then Change all the White back to Blue.

Comment: What if instead of "making all the comments blue", you instead were to use the Excel's built-in *comments* functionality?  (See: ["**Annotate a worksheet by using comments**"](https://support.office.com/article/annotate-a-worksheet-by-using-comments-bdcc9f5d-38e2-45b4-9a92-0b2b5c7bf6f8).)

Comment: Sigh... I just remembered that it's possible. Seems like I was trying to over complicate something. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check font color like so:

```
Sub CheckingA1ForBlueFont()

If Range("A1").Font.Color = vbBlue Then
    MsgBox "Font color of A1 value is blue!"
End If

End Sub
```

However, it will work only for this particular blue color (vbBlue).